# automatically add path in a MATLAB script

Tags: matlab

I have several MATLAB scripts to share with my colleagues. I have put these scripts under a specified directory, e.g., /home/sharefiles

Under the MATLAB command prompt, the users can use these scripts by typing

```
addpath  /home/sharefiles
```

Is there a way to automatically add this path in my matlab script, and save users the efforts of invoking `addpath  /home/sharefiles`  each time.

Answer (score 21):

Sure, just add the addpath to your script.

```
addpath('/home/sharefiles')
```

If you want to recursively add subdirectories, use the `genpath` function:

```
addpath(genpath('/home/sharefiles')
```

Adding files to the path or one of the slower operations in Matlab, so you probably don't want to put the `addpath` call in the inner loop of an operation.  You can also test to see if you need to add the path first.

```
if ~exist('some_file_from_your_tools.m','file')
    addpath('/home/sharefiles')
end
```

Or, more directly

```
if isempty(strfind(path,'/home/sharefiles;'))
    addpath('/home/sharefiles')
end
```

Comment: You could also add the code provided by Pursuit to your startup.m file so that the paths are added to the MATLAB path when MATLAB starts.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the code posted by Pursuit to your startup.m file so that MATLAB adds it to the path automaticlly upon startup. Or, take a look at the `savepath` function. Lastly,

Answer (score 0):

So when you Use the GUI to set path, the paths get added in the default start directory of Matlab in the pathdef.m file present there. Hence if you are running your code from any other directory either you would have to copy over this file or create a script in the startup folder. Hope this helps!!