# Is there any downside for calling MATLAB's addpath many times?

Tags: include, matlab

My questions is if addpath is similar to #include in C. In C if you don't add #include guard (#ifndef ...) there will be multiple definitions of function. But it seems that MATLAB is handling this issue.

I was using this scheme not to call addpath many times:

```
try
    f(sample args);
catch err
    addpath('lib');
end
```

But now I think it's not necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#include` adds a **specific header file**. `addpath` merely adds a folder to the search path and does not add any code to your program. Think of it as adding directories to search for header files in C++ (e.g. in Visual Studio, it's *"Additional Include Directories"* and g++, it's implemented with `-I`).

Also, I think `addpath` checks if the folder has already been added, so you're really not doing anything with the repeated calls to `addpath('lib')`.

Comment: Do you mean capital `-L` for g++?

Comment: Yes, `addpath` calls `path` function that checks if the directory already on the path. It changes the order though.

Comment: @AndrewJanke: Yes, but that messes up the analogy a bit. I'll go for `-I`.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple calls to `addpath` do not create multiple functions, so from a correctness point of view there is no problem with using `addpath` multiple times.

However, `addpath` is a relatively slow operation.  You shouldn't call it within a function that may be called many times during normal operation.

---

Edit:

Also, rather than relying on try/catch to check the current state of your path, you can check the path directly.  See examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8238096/931379.

Comment: You're right. I notice that. A single call to addpath takes about 20ms on my laptop.