# In Matlab 2011a the file that need to be loaded is put on which folder

Tags: matlab, file, directory, matlab-load

I'm having problem with MATLAB 2011a i.e. I want to load file of data in my program but I can't access it as I keep it in bin folder C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\bin 
& there  is no folder name as "work" as well. so where should I keep my data file to load it.

Comment: Look here: 
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237223/automatically-add-path-in-a-matlab-script

Comment: You can add the folder also by file->preferences->path... and there you can add/omit/arrange the folders which you want to access

Answer (score 0):

You will generally have write access to the first folder listed  by the [`userpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/userpath.html) function (e.g. G:\Users\Jon\Documents\MATLAB), which is automatically added to the search path on startup of MATLAB.

Note that adding folders to the `path` does NOT allow you to access *non*-MATLAB files (e.g. .dat, etc.) without either an absolute or relative path, or having the data file in your current working directory.